# ¿Como puedo corregir el error con los Entry en el comparator usando un HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparaciones, hashmap

Estoy utilizando un HashMap para ordenar un lista de objetos llamadas Criaturas. El cual utiliza una key llamada ID que es un String. Me piden que utilice el método Comparator para ordenarla y que cuando en el método a ordenarPorFortaleza(); , la fortaleza es un atributo, lo transforme en un arraylist y se ordene mediante el método Collections. El problema es que el compilador me marca error en todos los Entry que hay y no veo el porqué.

```
public List<Entry<String,Criatura>> ordenarPorFortaleza(){
List<Entry<String,Criatura>> mapaCriaturas2 = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Criatura>>(mapaCriaturas.entrySet());
Collections.sort(mapaCriaturas2,Criatura.FortalezaComparator);
return mapaCriaturas2;
```

}

```
public static Comparator<Entry<String,Criatura>> FortalezaComparator=new Comparator<Entry<String,Criatura>>(){

    public int compare(Entry<String,Criatura> comparando1,Entry<String,Criatura> comparando2){
    if(comparando1.getValue().getFortaleza()==comparando2.getValue().getFortaleza()){
      return comparando1.getValue().compareTo(comparando2.getValue());
    }else{
      if(comparando1.getValue().getFortaleza()<comparando2.getValue().getFortaleza()){
        return 1;
      }else{
        return -1;
      }
    }

  }
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que importar la interfaz `Entry`:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Es una interfaz anidada en la interfaz `java.util.Map`